# converting Matlab program to Mathematica code

Tags: code-review, matlab

I have the following Matlab program;

```
k=1:1:10;
a=[3,5,2];
for j=1:length(k)
for h =1:1:length(a)
    x=a(h);
    y1(h)=x^j-2;
end
minfind(j)=min(y1);
end
plot(k, minfind)
```

[image]

I tried to write Mathematica code that perform the same calculation. So far I wrote the following Mathematica code

```
a = ( { {3, 5, 2} } );
For[j = 1, j <= 10, j = j + 1,
 For[h = 1, h <= 3, h = h + 1,
  x = a [[1, h]];
  y22 = x^j-2;
  y1 = Append[y1, y22];
  ];
 ymin1 = Min[y1];
 minfind = Append[minfind, ymin1];
 ]
```

But the above code doesn't work.

Can anyone help in pointing what is wrong with the above code and what is the correct code?

Comment: `ListLinePlot@Table[Min[{3, 5, 2}^j - 2], {j, 10}]`?? But as written you can substitute `Min[]` for just `2^j-2`...

Comment: the only thing preventing your revised code from working is you need to initialize `minfind` and `y1` as empty lists.

Comment: @george2079 That was useful. I revised the code, it is working now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to know quite where to start with this, but I'd start with the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8) for some initial guidance.

As a general guide, nested `For` loops are almost never necessary and using list-based operations is much more efficient, as well as readable and less prone to error.

Let's take the inner loop first.

```
 For[h = 1, h <= 3, h = h + 1,
  x = a [[1, h]];
  y22 = x^j-2;
  y1 = Append[y1, y22]; ];
```

All you are really doing is constructing a vector of each element of `a` (respecifying `a` as a vector `{3, 5, 2}`) taken to the power `j` and then subtracting 2. By the way, is that what you want? or did you mean `x^(j-2)`?

So eliminate this loop by using the `Listable` property of arithmetic operations and writing

```
a^j - 2
```

You can eliminate most of the outer loop by changing this to

```
a^# - 2 & /@ Range[10]
```

Where `Range[10]` is what I think your definition of `k` in your Matlab code does. Evaluate that and check.

The result of the last line above is:

```
 {{1, 3, 0}, {7, 23, 2}, {25, 123, 6}, {79, 623, 14}, {241, 3123, 
  30}, {727, 15623, 62}, {2185, 78123, 126}, {6559, 390623, 
  254}, {19681, 1953123, 510}, {59047, 9765623, 1022}}
```

(Incidentally `Outer[#2^#1 - 2 &, Range[10], a]` gives the same output. You might want to experiment with some other list-based functions.)

You want the minimum of each row of that, so just use `Map` (shortcut notation `/@`) like this

```
Min /@ ( a^# - 2 & /@ Range[10])
```

And your result should be

```
{0, 2, 6, 14, 30, 62, 126, 254, 510, 1022}
```

Yes, all you need to replace that convoluted nested `For` loop is:

```
a =  {3, 5, 2};
Min /@ ( a^# - 2 & /@ Range[10])
```

Comment: @barznjy I'm afraid that the simple answer to your more complex question is essentially that you have to learn more about *Mathematica* if you want to use it. Trying to use *Mathematica* by translating Matlab code and practices won't take you very far. In addition to that, it is discouraged to have questions with "moving targets", where the OP keeps changing the nature of the problem... Verbeia gave you a thorough introduction to the *concepts* you need. Try and apply them on your own to the problem you mentioned in comments, but start from scratch rather than trying to adapt looping code!