# Converting Matlab code to Mathematica

Tags: code-review, conversion, matlab

I have following Matlab code:

```
xC= zeros(1,n);
yC= zeros(1,n);

for i=1:(b/delta);
    xC(i) = -a/2;
    yC(i) = b-(i-1/2)*delta;
end;
for i=1:(a/delta);
    xC(i+b/delta) = -a/2+(i-1/2)*delta;
    yC(i+b/delta) = 0;
end;
for i=1:(b/delta);
    xC(i+b/delta+a/delta) = a/2-(1/2)*delta;
    yC(i+b/delta+a/delta) = (i-1/2)*delta;
end;
```

Since i'm new to mathematica can anyone help me convert this to mathematica code.

explanation:
I am trying to create a matrices 1x300 (n=300).

creating empty matrices with this:

```
xC= zeros(1,n);
yC= zeros(1,n);
```

First For loop is filling first 50 elements of matrices with values `-a/2 and b-(i-1/2)*delta`. Second loop is filling the next 200 elements of matrices with values `-a/2+(i-1/2)*delta and 0` and the third loop is filling last 50 elements with `a/2-(1/2)*delta and (i-1/2)*delta`.

What i have tried with mathematica is this:

```
bdelta = b/delta
adelta = a/delta

xC = Table[0, {i, n}]
yC = Table[0, {i, n}];

xC = Table[-a/2, {i, bdelta}];
yC = Table[b - (i - 1/2)*delta, {i, bdelta}];

xC = Table[-a/2 + (i - 1/2)*delta, {i, bdelta + 1, adelta + bdelta}];
yC = Table[0, {i, bdelta + 1, bdelta + adelta}];

xC = Table[a/2 - (1/2)*delta, {i, bdelta + adelta + 1, n}];
yC = Table[(i - 1/2)*delta, {i, bdelta + adelta + 1, n}];
```

since it's not working and i have very little experience with mathematica and its syntax i would really need some help with this.

Comment: The first for loop is `xC = PadRight[ConstantArray[-a/2, Floor[b/delta]], n];` and `yC = PadRight[b - (Range[b/delta] - 1/2) delta, n];`. In the second for loop you write `yC(i+b/delta) = 0;` but these are already equal to `0` aren't they?!

Comment: Have a look at this timeless piece: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/764).

Comment: Have you tried anything? The idea is that OP should prove a minimal familiarity with Mathematica. Additionally, everything that does not concern MMA should be explained. I don't think `zeros(1,n)` is obvious.

Comment: @coolwater yes they are.

Comment: Similar: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91958/converting-matlab-program-to-mathematica-code

Comment: Both Matlab and Mathematica can process arrays without loops. Your first for-loop can be written `xC(1:b/delta) = -a./2; yC(1:b/delta) = b-((1:b/delta)-1/2).*delta;`, which can be translated `xC[[1 ;; Round[b/delta]] = -a/2; yC[[1 ;; Round[b/delta]] = b - (Range[b/delta] - 1/2) delta;`. If you strictly want `xC`, `yC` to be 1xn matrices instead of an n-vector, the instead of `xC[[..]]` etc, use `xC[[1, ..]]`

Comment: Your Matlab code doesn't run in Matlab.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster. Answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 5):

Less an answer than an extended comment.

You will get far greater response from this community it you show some Mathematica code that you've tried.

Additionally, you can go to [MATLAB's website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/index.html) and determine what MATLAB's functions and syntax do.

From that, start looking at Mathematica's built-in documentation or simply search the Internet.

Much of MATLAB's syntax operates contextually, e.g., "()" have a number of different uses.  I think you'll find Mathematica far more specific.

If memory serves, MATLAB could view the `n` in `zeros(1, n)` in any of a few ways, e.g. as :

- function
- class name
- variable or number
- scalar
- vector
- matrix

If you run `zeros(1, n)` in MATLAB it returns:

> Undefined function or variable 'n'.

So to give you a Mathematica equivalent, we need additional information.

What output do you want from `zeros(1, n)`?

- vector?
- matrix?
- other?

That said, a Mathematica equivalent might look like this:

```
Table[0, 10]
Table[0*i, {i, 10}]
Table[0*i, {i, 10}, {i, 10}]
```

A couple of the above likely being silly.

I just can't "know" want you want to accomplish from the question so far.

@gwr in his comment to your answer makes a great recommendation to look at:

[Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/764)

@coolwater's recommendations:

```
xC = PadRight[ConstantArray[-a/2, Floor[b/delta]], n]; 
yC = PadRight[b - (Range[b/delta] - 1/2) delta, n];
```

might work, but they seem to make assumptions about the variables.

Of course the loops themselves may have a context that @coolwater understands that I don't.

In short, give us some more information and try some things on your own.  Get specific about where you get stuck.

Welcome to the forum.